# Problems with " when entering formula via .FORMULA and trying to use a variable for row reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a bit of code that copies non contiguous cells numbers from one sheet and pastes them in another  sheet if their values do not exist in the new list.  I have insert a row at the end of the list and then paste the missing value and repeat until all missing values have been added.  When done I sort the column and apply formula in the adjacent columns to match the length of the newly expanded list.

I read in other questions that I can simply do

```
Range("A1:A13").Formula = "A1+B2"
```

and it will produce a column like

```
A1+B2
A2+B3
A3+B4
...
A13+B14
```

And that is great so that is what I did.

Then I discovered that I had issues with  formulas like:

```
=IF(B2="","",A1+B2)
```

Which was fixed after some searching to produce

```
=IF(B2="""","""",A1+B2)
```

and I thought I hast that solved until I tried something like

```
    =IF(B2="DOG","cat",A1+B2)
```

Which I initially tried

```
=IF(B2="""DOG""","""cat""",A1+B2)
```

which did not work and then figured out I had too many " and after some more research I adjusted it to

```
=IF(B2=""DOG"",""cat"",A1+B2)
```

So I thought I had this quote thing figured out, but it turns out I am getting lost in the quotes somewhere.

So my working formula in excel is:

```
=IF(C14="","",HYPERLINK(MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1)),FIND("]", CELL("filename",$A$1))-FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1))+1)&"'"&C14&"'!$A$1",VLOOKUP(C14,ItemList,2,0)))
```

Basically I am generating a hyperlink to another worksheet.  I have a variable that tracks the first row `14` in this case, so I tried code this into the formula so I could change the first row variable easily if it ever changed rather than going through all my hard coded formulas and updating them.  As a result I wound up with the following line of code which keeps causing an error when the line is executed:

```
Dim Item_List_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Item_List_First_Row As Long
Dim Item_List_Max_Row As Long

Item_List_First_Row = 14
Item_List_Max_Row = Item_List_First_Row + Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Item_List_Sheet.Range("B:B")) - 1

Item_List_Sheet.Range("B" & Item_List_First_Row & ":" & "B" & Item_List_Max_Row).Formula = "=MAX($B$" & Item_List_First_Row - 1 & ":B" & Item_List_First_Row - 1 & ")+1"
'the above formula works as intended

'the formula below causes problems
Item_List_Sheet.Range("D" & Item_List_First_Row & ":" & "D" & Item_List_Max_Row).Formula = "=IF(C" & Item_List_First_Row & "="""","""",HYPERLINK(MID(CELL(""filename"",$A$1),FIND(""["",CELL(""filename"",$A$1)),FIND(""]"", CELL(""filename"",$A$1))-FIND(""["",CELL(""filename"",$A$1))+1)&""'""C" & Item_List_First_Row & "'!$A$1"",VLOOKUP(C" & Item_List_First_Row & ",ItemList,2,0)))"
```

Can someone see where I am going wrong?

#### UPDATE

I tried adjusting the formula as per GSerg comment that two & were missing and I still get the error message:

```
Item_List_Sheet.Range("D" & Item_List_First_Row & ":" & "D" & Item_List_Max_Row).Formula = "=IF(C" & Item_List_First_Row & "="""","""",HYPERLINK(MID(CELL(""filename"",$A$1),FIND(""["",CELL(""filename"",$A$1)),FIND(""]"", CELL(""filename"",$A$1))-FIND(""["",CELL(""filename"",$A$1))+1)&""'""&C" & Item_List_First_Row & ""&'!$A$1"",VLOOKUP(C" & Item_List_First_Row & ",ItemList,2,0)))"
```

Comment: You missed two `&`s in the `"'"&C14&` part, and you didn't double up the `"` right after that.

Comment: @Gserg found it thank you!!!!